# Where can I find kubelet logs on Container OS?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, kubelet

So I can see them under `var/log/messages` in the pods running other OS but I can't locate kubelet logs for the machines running [Container OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os).

Answer (score 1):

Container-Optimized OS uses the `systemd-journald` service to collect system logs, so Docker and Kubelet logs are in `/var/log/journal`.

You can also run `journalctl` to view the logs.

Answer (score 0):

kubelet logs can be see using journalctl.

`journalctl -u kubelet` or `journalctl --unit kubelet`